# Difference between the formula of Roger Cotes and Euler

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms, math-history

What was the difference between the formula that Roger cotes derived and that euler got? I mean to say that Euler got the following formula : 
$$e^{ix} = \cos x+i \sin x$$

And Cotes got the following :
$$ix = \ln(\cos x + i\sin x)$$

We can directly see that it is same as euler's

Comment: Well, to be precise, the first form holds for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, while the second cannot hold for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the complex logarithm is multivalued under the current definition. Therefore Cotes' formula is not really true anymore, but it was when he got it.

Comment: I like this answer! I've asked the follow-up question [How has the definition of the complex logarithm changed over time?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2395338/284619)