# How did the definition of complex logarithm evolve since Cotes (1682-1716)?

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms, math-history

From the question [Difference between the formula of Roger Cotes and Euler](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1315733/284619):

> Euler: $e^{ix} = \cos x+i \sin x$
>
> Cotes: $ix = \ln(\cos x + i\sin x)$

The [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1315758/284619) (in full):

> The problem is that the complex logarithm is multivalued under the current definition. Therefore Cotes' formula is not really true anymore, but it was when he got it.

This raises the question *How has the definition of the complex logarithm evolved since Cotes?*

I assume the answer suggests that log was *single valued* in Cotes' time, since it is multivalued now. Was it in fact of the same general form as it is now but with a single breakpoint in $\theta$?

Was it something like $ln(r) + i\theta$ and $-\pi \lt \theta \le \pi$ for example?

If not, please explain the change in the definition of logarithm from Cotes's time to now in such a way that someone with a basic working knowledge of complex numbers who's just read Wikipedia's [Complex Logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm) could understand.

**below:** *A plot of the multi-valued imaginary part of the complex logarithm function, which shows the branches. As a complex number z goes around the origin, the imaginary part of the logarithm goes up or down. This makes the origin a branch point of the function.* From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm):

[image: Riemann surface of log(z), projection from 4dim C x C to 3dim C x Im(C), color is argument.]

> Riemann surface of Log[z], projection from 4dim C x C to 3dim C x Im(C), color is argument. Source: [Riemann surface log](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Riemann_surface_log.svg)

Comment: $\log(ab)= \log(a)+\log(b)+2ik \pi$

Comment: @reuns I'm asking how the definition of log has changed over time. It seems it was single-valued in Cotes' time, so that *would not yet have applied* then, correct?

Comment: I would be skeptical that Cotes' formula is actually $ix = \ln(\cos(x) + i \sin(x))$ -- it may be a translation into modern language, and things can be lost in translation.

Comment: @Hurkyl I never said my `math-history` question was easy. I would not know where to begin, so I've asked for help here.

Comment: @uhoh Locally you can choose $\log$ such that $k = 0$ but in general $k \ne 0$ and depends on $a,b$. Therefore your formula is not true. See a course on the construction of the complex logarithm as a local antiderivative of $\frac{1}{z}$ and how $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z} dz =2i \pi\ne 0$ implies the different branches of $\log$. This is known and didn't change since more than 200 years.

Comment: @reuns you mean my "Was it something like..." formula? You are writing in present tense, but my question is about the work of Roger Cotes, 1682 -1716. I'm not asking what log is now, I'm asking *what it was then*.

Comment: No, you are really asking about the maths behind the multivaluedness and the different branches of $\log$, as this is the answer.

Comment: The formula $\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b)$ is true in $\mathbb{C}/2i\pi \mathbb{Z}$ (modulo $2i \pi$). I think before Cauchy complex analysis was a mess, and was more symbolic than rigorous.

Comment: @reuns you seem to be stuck in present tense, and therefore are simply missing the point of my question altogether. Please post this as an answer so that I can see how well received it is by others.

Comment: This question can only be answered with the real Cote's definition. The given answer shouldn't be taken for a formal statement !

Comment: @uhoh. Sorry to have disturbed you.

Comment: @YvesDaoust oh no, not at all! My thorough reply was only to head off others who might pick up where you left off and then claim my question was off topic or could not be answered. I have more experience than most people being a low-rep user in a new site, and these things can happen quickly and unpredictably.

Comment: @YvesDaoust [History of the Exponential and Logarithmic Concepts](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2974078?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) Cajori, Florian; Amer. Math. Mon. 20, 2 (Feb 1913) pp. 35-47 may cover this particular issue. I'll also add this link to my question. It contains a discussion of and passages by several noted mathematicians of the time. I'll put a link into the question as well. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: It might be worthwhile to ask this question on the History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange https://hsm.stackexchange.com. See for example a perhaps related question https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/4907/eulers-first-proof-of-eix-cosxi-sinx/4908#4908 and some answers and comments which mention Cotes's work. Somebody there might know something about the evolution of the idea since Cotes. (And probably they would understand your question better, too.)

Comment: @ZachTeitler thanks for the suggestion! I've [posted a link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40960226#40960226) to this question in hsm chat. If there's interest, I'll move it. I don't think my question is *too hard* for mathematicians to understand of course, but perhaps the idea that the definition of the complex logarithm could evolve over time is too unsettling? :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The emphasis on the single-valuedness of a function is a fairly recent phenomenon.  Cauchy in his [Cours d'Analyse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cours_d%27Analyse) (1821) deals in detail with multiple-valued functions for which he uses a double-symbol notation, such as $\sqrt{~}\!\!\!\!\sqrt{x}$ (to account for both roots in this case).  If so, Cotes' formula was legitimate for his historical period.

Today we incorporate single-valuedness into our definition of a function following mid-19th century authors, so such a definition is no longer adequate.

Comment: I've clarified the question a bit, I'm looking for literally how it changed. *What was* the definition of the complex logarithm then, and in what way has it changed. I've taken a guess in the question, but I'm not sure. Thanks!

Comment: I've decided to split off the more historical (rather than mathematical) aspects of the question to a separate (future) question in [HSM SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/). I think this covers the mathematical aspects quite nicely, *thanks!*